# Listing all files in www/imgs directory phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, fileapi

Hello im having a hard time dealing with phonegap 3.4.0 file system api.

Im developing an ios application, in the www folder i have an imgs folder which have like 16 pictures. I can write their names like this  but I want to access those files urls dynamically with phonegap api. I have tried every tutorial but all of them didn't work. I dont quit understand how phonegap file system works. Can I accsess files on the www folder with phonegap api? if not where should I put the files in xcode, in which folder? and how can I get their url and use them in my project??!! like listing all the files in a folder on some other file than www. but also I need to know in which folder should i store my files? can some one help please?  Im so confused ;( phonegap file docs are so confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using phonegap 3.4.0, then there is staging folder, where you can find your www directory. put all the files in that directory. You can directly access those files.

[image]

to get image from image folder in www you don't need phonegap api.

try these for static :  `<img class="maprelicon " alt="Search Location" src="images/loclistico.png" />` u will get that particular image..

and to set image dynamically try these..
$("#elementID").attr('src','images/first.png');

let me know if its not working...

Comment: Thank you for your answer that's not what I meant?
I have like un know number of images in the file www/imgs